# Is there a way to re-encode an MP3 or any other audio file in Android?

Tags: android, audio, mp3, encode

I have a source MP3 file, and it's unknown how many channels it has, or the sampling rate. I need to re-encode it so that the resulting file is mono and 8kHz samling rate. The format is unimportant, as long as MediaPlayer can play it. Is there anything in the SDK that allows me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to play it over a bluetooth headset?

I experimented with that a while back, but didn't use the MediaPlayer. Instead, I used an approach more like the one here:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/580/android-audio-play-a-wav-file-on-an-audiotrack/

I was able to get mono audio over bluetooth working, but it's a real pain. Since the app was just for personal use, I eventually decided to just get a better bluetooth headset that supported the new stereo audio standard. With a stereo headset, you don't have to write any code at all - just turn on bluetooth, sync with the device, and you're done.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll check out the post you referenced, but I actually have no need to transcode in real-time -- i can download an MP3 (usually small, under 1 min long), and convert it to any other format that will play over BT.

Comment: There is another post on the same blog to do it with MP3s:http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/

Comment: I could be completely wrong about this, because it's been a long time since I tried, but I think the issue was that you have to play it on the phone specific channel, and (at least at the time) the MediaPlayer wouldn't let you do that. I *think* that's what lead me to the AudioTrack approach.

Comment: I've played around with this for a bit, and I definitely need it to end up as a file -- so AudioTrack doesn't work. I looked at JLayer, but that doesn't seem to allow downsampling to 8000 Hz. I'm going to post another question to see if downsampling is even possible

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no.

There doesn't seem to be a way to use MediaPlayer/MediaRecorder to transcode an MP3 (hypothetically... unless you're looking for a low-quality transcoding, i.e. play the MP3 file using MediaPlayer and setup MediaRecorder to record whatever's coming in through the microphone - some of that audio would be the MP3 you're playing).

Transcode the MP3 file on your local desktop computer is your best bet.

Comment: This doesn't need to be done in real-time, but it does have to be done on the handset. Are there any 3rd party libraries (like LAME) that can do this? I saw a LAME encoder on the market, but can't figure out where the code came from.

Comment: That's only part of the solution. I doubt LAME would accept the AMR-NB format that most Android devices use for audio recording. You could look at porting some C/C++ audio transcoding software to Android via the NDK and interface to the Java side via JNI.